# integrate kafka with Odoo

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-kafka, odoo

I have Odoo front end on aws ec2 instance and connected it with postgresql on [ElephentQl](https://www.elephantsql.com/) site with 15 concurrent connections
so I want to make sure that this connection limits will pose no problem so i wanna use kafka to perform database write instead of Odoo doing it directly but found no recourses online to help me out

Comment: Postgres can easily handle 15 connections. How would Kafka help with that?

Comment: i mean postgres can handle max 15 connections in the plan i am buying
so i need kafka to queue db Writes to database to handle this limitation

Comment: Okay, well, Odoo is written in Python. There are Python Kafka clients, but you might have to write your own Odoo code/plugins to integrate the two

Comment: isnt there an easier way to do it with out adding custom python code as i am a django nodejs developer and only need to solve this problem on an Odoo server and i have next to 0 experience in odoo

Comment: You could make one of your 15 connections a Debezium client that'll pull from the database into Kafka. Otherwise, you can search Odoo source code to see that kafka clients aren't used

Comment: As an aside: if you're using EC2, why not use RDS for your database? Then you can have more connections... Otherwise, you're probably paying more for AWS egress traffic

Answer (score 1):

Is your issue about Connection Pooling? PostgreSQL includes two implementations of DataSource for JDBC 2 and two for JDBC 3, as shown [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-datasource.html).

```
dataSourceName  String  Every pooling DataSource must have a unique name.

initialConnections  int The number of database connections to be created when the pool is initialized.

maxConnections  int The maximum number of open database connections to allow.
                    When more connections are requested, the caller will hang until a connection is returned to the pool.
```

The pooling implementations do not actually close connections when the client calls the close method, but instead return the connections to a pool of available connections for other clients to use. This avoids any overhead of repeatedly opening and closing connections, and allows a large number of clients to share a small number of database connections.

Additionally, you might want to investigate, **Pgbouncer**. Pgbouncer is a stable, in-production connection pooler for PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL doesn’t realise the presence of PostgreSQL. Pgbouncer can do load handling, connection scheduling/routing and load balancing. Read more from [this blog](https://webkul.com/blog/integrate-pgbouncer-with-odoo/) that shows how to integrate this with Odoo. There are a lot of references from this page.

Finally, I would second [OneCricketeer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) comment, above, on using Amazon RDS, unless you are getting a far better deal with [ElephantSQL](https://www.elephantsql.com/).

On using Kafka, you have to realise that Odoo is a frontend application that is synchronous to user actions, therefore you are not architecturally able to have a functional system if you put Kafka in-between Odoo and the database. You would input data and see it in about 2-10 minutes. I exaggerate but; If that is what you really want to do then by all means, invest the time and effort.

[Read more from Confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/bottled-water-real-time-integration-of-postgresql-and-kafka/), the team behind Kafka that came out of LinkedIn on how they use a solution called BottledWater to do some cool streams over PostgreSQL, that should be more like what you want to do.

Do let us know which option you selected and what worked! Keep the community informed.